# What's the meaning of "explicit-control" in "explicit-control evaluator"?

Tags: scheme, sicp

The section 5.4 of SICP develops an evaluator written in an assembly, but I can't figure out why they call it explicit-control evaluator.

Comment: Does it really matter? Why were you named alice? I cant figure it out ;p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up until this point we were writing interpreters that run over the underlying machine's architecture with its own registers and operations. In a way, we don't truly have control of what's happening down there.

Now, we're going to build a virtual machine in which we'll have explicit control over the registers, operations, jumps, etc. - sure, this virtual machine will *also* be running on top of the physical machine, but you'll be able to see how things work at a very low level ;)

Answer (score 1):

First, while SICP *happens* to write an evalutor for Scheme in Scheme [or for [JS in JS](https://sourceacademy.org/sicpjs/making-of) — I'll be linking to the dual-language edition here], they did it mostly so that students who only learnt that one language can follow.
The ideas and terminology are all applicable in the more common case where underlying aka. *host language* ≠ *interpreted language*.

#### Consider how the previous [eval/apply evaluator](https://sicp.sourceacademy.org/chapters/4.1.1.html) handled control flow.

Specifically, when one procedure calls another procedure, how did control enter it, and later return to the calling procedure?

Well, the evaluator itself was written recursively!
When handling a procedure call aka. application — `(proc_expr arg1_expr arg2_expr)` [or in JS terms, `func_expr(arg1_expr, arg2_expr)`]:

- `eval` first calls itself on argument expressions, and on the procedure.
  This does NOT represent recursion in the interpreted language — simply its expected [order of computation](https://sicp.sourceacademy.org/chapters/4.2.1.html).
  But it is recursive in the host language — to a fixed depth, it's descending the syntax tree.
- it then calls `apply`, which (in the `compound-procedure?` case) calls `eval` on the procedure's body.
  This represents the call tree in the interpreted language — it MAY represent recursion, iff the called procedure is the same as the caller, or one of the higher callers.
  Regardless, this is always (mutually) recursive in the host language.

[I'm using here the word "recursive" without SICP's distinction whether it makes tail-calls — resulting in "iterative process" — on not]

=> So, it's "implicit control" in the sense that interpreted language's stack is nowhere to be seen in the evaluator's code — it's implicit in `eval`/`apply` calling each other, and it will live in memory on the *host language's stack*.  As their footnote admits:

> [1] Even so, there will remain important aspects of the evaluation process that are not elucidated by our evaluator. The most important of these are the detailed mechanisms by which procedures functions call other procedures functions and return values to their callers. We will address these issues in chapter 5, where we take a closer look at the evaluation process by implementing the evaluator as a simple register machine.

It also inherits any of the host's limitations on stacks.  some examples:

- if the host language doesn't guarantee tail call optimization, an interpreter written in this style can't guarantee it either.
- if the host language doesn't have exceptions / non-local exits (aborting out of multiple nested calls), the interpreted language can't provide them either.
- unless the host language provides powerful stack introspection, it will be hard to print stack traces, and nearly impossible to implement continuations.

---

#### An ["explicit control" evaluator](https://sicp.sourceacademy.org/chapters/5.4.html) OTOH answers all those questions by managing its own stack, and spelling out how exactly call/return work.

It uses the host language in a very "flat" way.  There are some function calls but that's just for structure, they *could* all be inlined into one large loop (or even a hardware circuit).

This approach is free to implement any control flow the interpreted language needs.  The interpreted program threw an exception and you want to unwind multiple stack frames?  Go ahead, the interpreted language's stack is now a regular data structure.

Function calls are now handled under [compound-apply](https://sicp.sourceacademy.org/chapters/5.4.1.html#p12) [in JS, [here](https://sicp.sourceacademy.org/chapters/5.4.2.html#p15)], and they explicitly save to/restore from the stack.